# The Confusing Value of Variable 'y'

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int x,y,z;
    x=y=z=-1;
    z = ++x && ++y || ++z;
    printf("x=%d, y=%d, z=%d", x, y, z);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, the program is printing x=0, y=-1, z=0.
But according to the increment (++y), shouldn't the value of 'y' also equal to 0?
Please Explain.

I expected the code to print x=0, y=0, z=0.
The actual result was x=0, y=-1, z=0.

Comment: The logic operators `&&` and `||` uses [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If the left-hand side of `&&` is "false" (and `0` is considered false) then the right-hand side will not be evaluated. What resources are you using to learn C? Any decent book, class or tutorial should have mentioned it.

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  You can't do `x = ++x;` which is essentially what you're doing with `z` in `z = ++x && ++y || ++z;` in this case.  There's no sequence point between `++z` and the assignment to `z`, so the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Arguably, "chained" assignments like `x=y=z=-1` invoke undefined behavior. The side effect of updating `z` is unsequenced in relation to the value computation of `z`. The C standard was made less clear here as per C11.

Comment: @TomKarzes You're not the only one who noticed it, although rather than being like `x = ++x;` it is like `x = !!++x;`. Still UB though.

Comment: @Lundin What is undefined about *"An assignment expression has the value of the left operand after the assignment"*?

Comment: @TomKarzes I was busy reading the relevant parts of the standard. :-)

Comment: Yash, if your question is about the `&&` and `||` operators, I suggest you remove `z = ` from the relevant line to clarify this.

Comment: @IanAbbott Does that mean that in the expression `z=-1` there is a value computation of `z` after the assignment? The standard isn't clear. It was clear before C11. "An assignment expression has a value obtained through a miracle" isn't helpful - where is the value coming from? it can either be a temporary variable or a value computation of `z`.

Comment: @Lundin I take it to mean the value `z` would have after the assignment even if the side effect of storing to the object denoted by `z` hasn't actually happened yet.

Comment: @Lundin I'm still trying to figure out why you say it was clear before C11 since the wording is unchanged since C89, although a footnote was added in C11 onwards.

Comment: @IanAbbott C99 6.5.16 §4 emphasis mine "The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. If an attempt is made to modify the result of an assignment operator **or to access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.**" Whereas C11 just removed all of that and left it undocumented.

Comment: @Lundin the removal was decided at the WG14 April 2008 meeting ([draft minutes WG14/N1300](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1300.pdf) section 9.3), referencing papers [WG14/N1285](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1285.htm) and [WG14/N1253](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1253.htm).

Comment: Yeah my bad, it is evaluated. Casting final close vote then, to the usual duplicate.

Comment: @Lundin If I understand correctly, `z = (++x && ++y) || ++z;` is UB, while `z = ++z || (++x && ++y);` is not. If this is true, editing the question with the latter may be useful for the OP, to understand the fact that `y` doesn't get incremented.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana Thats a different scenario entirely and it relies on the sequence point in the `||` operator. The only thing people need to learn from this is to not write such code in the first place...